# how to assign lua variable by reference

Tags: lua

How can I assign a variable by reference in Lua to another one?

For example:  want to do equivalent of "a = b" where a will then be a pointer to b

Background:
have a case where I have effectively something like this:

```
local a,b,c,d,e,f,g   -- lots of variables

if answer == 1 then
  -- do stuff with a
elsif answer == 1 then
  -- do stuff with b
.
.
.
```

PS. For example in the below it appears apparent the b=a is by value.  NOTE: I'm using Corona SDK.

```
a = 1
b = a
a = 2
print ("a/b:", a, b)

-- OUTPUT: a/b: 2   1
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

EDIT: regarding your clarifed post and example, there is no such thing as a the type of reference you want in Lua. You want a variable to refer to another variable. In Lua, variables are simply names for values. That's it.

The following works because `b = a` leaves both `a` and `b` referring to the same table value:

```
a = { value = "Testing 1,2,3" }
b = a

-- b and a now refer to the same table
print(a.value) -- Testing 1,2,3
print(b.value) -- Testing 1,2,3

a = { value = "Duck" }

-- a now refers to a different table; b is unaffected
print(a.value) -- Duck
print(b.value) -- Testing 1,2,3
```

---

You can think of all variable assignments in Lua as by reference.

This is technically true of tables, functions, coroutines, and strings. It *may as well* be true of numbers, booleans, and nil, because these are immutable types, so as far as your program is concerned, there's no difference.

For example:

```
t = {}
b = true
s = "testing 1,2,3"
f = function() end

t2 = t -- t2 refers to the same table
t2.foo = "Donut"
print(t.foo) -- Donut

s2 = s -- s2 refers to the same string as s
f2 = f -- f2 refers to the same function as f
b2 = b -- b2 contains a copy of b's value, but since it's immutable there's no practical difference
-- so on and so forth --
```

---

Short version: this only has practical implications for mutable types, which in Lua is userdata and table. In both cases, assignment is copying a reference, not a value (i.e. not a clone or copy of the object, but a pointer assignment).

Comment: but I've just tried and put the example in the PS of the main post - it seems not to work

Comment: What you're trying doesn't work. Assignments in Lua copy references to a value. A variable contains a value, it is not a value itself. You can't store a pointer/reference to a variable in another variable.

Comment: ok thanks - so I guess what I am doing is possible but I'll need to house the variables within a table then right?

Answer (score -1):

It's true the variables are just names for values. But you can compute variable names, if you are dealing with keys in a table. This means you can use key names to perform your conditional logic.

```
myvars = { a=1, b=2, c=3.14 }

function choose(input)
    print(myvars[input])
end

choose('a')
choose('b')
a = 'a'
choose(a)
b = a
choose(b)
a = 'c'
choose(a)
choose(b)
```

Output:

```
1
2
1
1
3.14
1
```

Comment: much more like a jump table in C++