# How to get variables that not declared yet but will declared soon?

Tags: lua

How can I get variables that not declared yet?

Here are simple example:

```
a = b
b = 123
```

What I want from these 2 lines is `a` << `123`. But obv it doesn't work.

I know the easy way to get the answer `a = 123` is cut 1st line and paste it to lower than 2nd line.

But I'm in some problem. I need some function like 'WillDeclaredVar()' that I can use in like this:

```
a = WillDeclaredVar(b)
sheepCount = 123
b = sheepCount
print(a)
```

so I can get the answer '123'.

Or there are any built-in functions that will allows me to do similar thing?

===

I think the link given by timrau is not telling my case. the key point is how to get Variables 'that not declared yet'.

===

Adding actual Code:

```
triggerCount = 0 -- Counting number of 'Trigger' function
local Trigger = function (t)
triggerCount = triggerCount + 1
return Trigger (t)
end


-- following Triggers are same as while statement.
-- following Triggers doing: Add 1 MarineCount until get 64000 MarineCount



Trigger { -- Here the Trigger function. Now triggerCount = 1.
    players = {P1}
    actions = {
        SetDeaths(P1, Add, 1, "Terran Marine")
    },
flag = {preserved},
}
Portal(LoopStart);
-- function Portal(VariableName) returns VariableName = triggerCount. So LoopStart = 1.

Trigger { -- Now triggerCount = 2.
    players = {P1}
    actions = {
        LinkList(LoopEnd, LoopStart);
-- function LinkList(From, To) changes 'From' Trigger's next pointer to the 'To' Trigger.
-- But now the problem happens. Because 'LoopEnd' is not declared yet.
    },
flag = {preserved},
}


Trigger { -- Now triggerCount = 3.
    players = {P1}
    conditions = {
        Deaths(P1, Exactly, 64000, "Terran Marine");
    }
    actions = {
        _LinkList(LoopEnd);
        -- Reset LoopEnd's next pointer(= LoopEscape) if MarineCount hits 64000
    },
flag = {preserved},
}
Portal(LoopEnd); -- LoopEnd = 3.
```

1. Changing Order of Triggers will break the Trigger logic(while statement).
2. All i want is get easy to coding. To put in bluntly, I don't need to solve this problem(get undeclared var). I can imagine a few ways to avoid it. But if i using these ways then the coding work will be very complicated and the difficulty of coding will increases greatly. The difficulty made me stop coding in recent months.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to assign lua variable by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218330/how-to-assign-lua-variable-by-reference)

Comment: How to get a variable that doesn't exist? You don't. Your example makes no sense. Simply move `a =` below the `b =` line. Done. Your example in no way explains why you need this. Please give a real world example that's not trivially fixed with no side effects by simply reordering lines.

Comment: This smells a lot like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need this? What is your real problem?

Comment: @Mud In actual code, there is a lots of functions. these functions need to be stay in correct order and don't move. It's all about sc1 mapmaking. So the order of function(and/or triggers) is are very important. especially when i'm trying to manage linkList of the whole functions. So yes. Trying to get a variable that doesn't exist is impossible normally. But why i asked this question is:

Comment: 1. I am bigginer of Lua so i thought maybe there's some way to avoid it. 2. Someone did it with 8~900 line by python. And he said it was very hard to making it work for real. i hope you do not felt the language barrier

Comment: Try taking a look at how Moonscript handles this. Moonscript lets you get the variables beforehand.

Comment: "In actual code, there is a lots of functions." Then it shouldn't be hard to give an example of one.

Comment: The "real code" contains syntax errors and missing code. Can you turn it into working code and explain what it's trying to do?

Comment: That code's concept was explan of problem, and nothing more. But if you delete undefined functions 'Portal()' and 'LinkList()' it'll work on TeP(https://github.com/phu54321/TrigEditPlus) by base script(https://github.com/phu54321/TrigEditPlus/blob/master/TrigEditPlus/Editor/Encoder/basescript.lua).

Comment: If you need to know what is this and how to compile with it, here the steps: 1) run scmdraft2 2) File > New > Create Map 3) Triggers > TrigEdit++

Comment: Link to download ScmDraft2 = https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0BzNT-_7OuN7HRXgyQ3V3cjNpX3M&export=download

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I just felt that you really want to understand why i need to solve this problem.

Comment: Now i'll explain why: 1. Trigger's running order in starCraft1 is First trigger -> Last trigger. And at the last trigger if theres no more pointer that introduce to next trigger, then ends one cycle. (12 cycle per second) The bad thing is sc1 mapEditor doesn't support for, while, and many other statements and functions.

Comment: 2. One day, someone find a way to control pointers. It means now we can change order of triggers(= linklist). it also means now we can make a statements by trigger only. (TeP is also can use statements because it support lua, but its just like macro or looper. it not touchs pointer)

Comment: 3. So I made some code that manages linklist, and some functions too. (ex Portal(), LinkList() ect...) And now, the problem is happened as you can see in the code.

Comment: it's a problem of complication. I just want to get retired cause if i can't solve this problem in this way(get variable that not declared yet) then the coding is getting hard and complicated. i hope i explained enough for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make `var1` be a reference for `var2` write `var1 = ReferenceF or var2` (please note a space inside "ReferenceFor"!)

```
do
   local values, references, reference_flag = {}, {}
   setmetatable(_G, {
      __index = function (_, name)
         if name == 'ReferenceF' then
            reference_flag = true
         elseif reference_flag then
            reference_flag = false
            return {[references] = name}
         elseif references[name] then
            return _G[references[name]]
         else
            return values[name]
         end
      end,
      __newindex = function (_, name, val)
         if type(val) == 'table' and val[references] then
            references[name] = val[references]
         else
            values[name] = val
         end
      end
   })
end

a = ReferenceF or b  -- a is Reference For b
b = ReferenceF or c  -- b is Reference For c
sheepCount = 123
c = sheepCount
print(a, b, c)  --> 123 123 123
```

Comment: Ohh... Thanks! It's perfect! Even my question was dumb and i don't know why error happens when compile it by TeP(https://github.com/phu54321/TrigEditPlus) o>-< Anyway nice job. Thank you again! if no further answers for the newly added actual problem, i will confirm it as a answer

Comment: I don't like this answer because of using globals and overwriting the metatable of the environment. It's not safe and bad for performance.

Comment: @Youka - "Using globals" was the requirement of the author. But this solution can be easily adapted to using variables inside other tables instead of `_G`.  About safety: in general this solution is unsafe because of ignoring previous metatable of `_G`.  But the system used by the author seems to not use metatable for `_G`, so it is safe in this particular case.  About performance: yes, using proxy table for globals has some performance impact.  Not critically high though: scripting subsystem used by the author is not a bottleneck of its host application, so don't worry be happy

Comment: Confirmed. Guess I need to ask one more question with more detailed explanation. By the way, did you think you can solve the actual code's problem? I don't know that much things about Lua but i have some idea. In my opinion, if with using the file reading function for itself(i mean the lua script file), I think I could count how many time the function 'Trigger' is called, also, then I could get the variables that would defined by the function 'portal()' beforehand.

Comment: I mean... something like: io.open(file, itself) THEN find.string("Trigger", ...) THEN if find the string "Portal" then... (...) ... I hope you understood what i'm talking about

Comment: @unknown02 - I didn't understand your "actual code's problem".

Comment: Uhm... Lemme explain. At first, if you compile that 'actual code' with base script(that i didn't write in this question), then the 'Trigger' functions will getting in starCraft1's 'TriggerBox'. For example, if you write 'Trigger(Add, 1, Gas, once)'  and put it in TriggerBox and save it, in game, your Gas will increase 1 point.

Comment: If you write 'Trigger(Add, 1, Gas, endlessly)' and save it into TriggerBox, in game- your Gas will increase 1 point every time 1 second passes.

Comment: If you write 3 triggers similarly as above(actual code), your Gas will increase 64000 point at once.

Comment: ps // In game, All the triggers are connected by Doubly Linked List. Trigger's running order in starCraft1 is First trigger -> Last trigger. And at the last trigger, if theres no more pointer that introduce to next trigger, then ends one cycle. 1 cycle per second. (note: somehow it can be 12~24 cycle per second, or more? ...nvm, i think it's not that important >.>)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get variables that not declared yet?

Short of time travel, you can't.

Your example code doesn't explain the motivation for the question, because this:

```
a = WillDeclaredVar(b)
sheepCount = 123
b = sheepCount
print(a)
```

Can trivially be rearranged into this:

```
sheepCount = 123
b = sheepCount
a = WillDeclaredVar(b)
print(a)
```

It would be easier to answer your question if you showed the actual problem you're trying to solve (to avoid an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)).

However, as stated there are few things we can note.

First, you need to distinguish between *declaring* a variable and *giving it a value*. In Lua you can say:

```
local b
```

To declare `b` as a local variable, which presumably will make a slot for it in the stack frame and let you bind closures to it, before you give it a value. However, the line:

```
a = WillDeclaredVar(b)
```

Will pass `WillDeclaredVar` the value that `b` *currently* has, and there's no way for `a` to change retroactively as a result of `b` being assigned a new value. That's simply not going to happen, ever. Neither `a` nor `WillDeclaredVar` are even aware that `b` exists, they are receive the value it contains at the point of call.

You could however bind the variable `b` to a closure which will fetch `b`'s current value when needed.

```
-- declare b before giving it a value, aka "forward reference"
local b
a = function() return b end
sheepCount = 123
b = sheepCount
print(a()) -- call a to get b's current value
```

Another way to do that would be to make `b` a *global* variable, which is really just a key into your environment table, so you *could* say:

```
a = WillDeclaredVar('b')
```

And have `a` be some object that can fetch the current value of `__ENV['b']` when required.

However, neither of these will support this syntax:

```
print(a)
```

`a` needs to be a function, something that looks up the value of `b` when needed rather than simply holding a previously computed value. You could do it in this particular instance (i.e. `a` needs to be convertable to a string), by creating a proxy object that implements `__tostring`.

```
function WillDeclaredVar(variableName)
    local proxy = { environment = _ENV or _G, variableName = variableName }
    return setmetatable(proxy, {
        __tostring = function(proxy)
            return proxy.environment[proxy.variableName]
        end
    })
end

-- a will compute a value based on the current value of b when needed
a = WillDeclaredVar('b')
sheepCount = 123
b = sheepCount
print(a)
```

Output:

```
123
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. i was in the XY Problem though. Could you review my question with the newly added code?

Comment: Just using tables would be much easier and cheaper :/ A closure needs some stack space and resources on call.