# Monitor a variable for changes in lua

Tags: function, lua

1) how do I create a function that monitors a variable for changes?

I am looking for some sort of operator to monitor a variable for changes and direction of change.   Way back, I used VB to test if a variable has changed.  They were called trigger+ve, trigger-ve, and udptrigger.  My goal is to create a Text-To-Speech script that acts like a virtual flight instructor in a flight simulator.    If the target altitude is 2000 feet, and the student deviates 200 feet to high, then the voice should say.  "You are too high, descend to 2000 feet".  For this case, I would like to monitor the variable  alt_delta, which is the difference between the target altitude (target_alt) and the current indicated altitude (alt_ind).  I have the code to find alt_delta, but now I want to monitor the newly created delta variable.  So a trigger+ve event will occur if alt_delta moves from 198 feet to 202 feet.  In this case, the trigger is satisfied, and the code will send an event to play the sound.

I have created three functions that will test the three types of triggers:

```
function **triggerpos** (var_test, value_test)   
--  var_test is the variable to monitor, like "alt_delta"
--  value_test is the trigger point, like 200 

function **triggerneg** (var_test, value_test) 

function **monitor** (var_test)
```

So in the above example with altitude delta, the code would look like:

```
function monitor_alt ()

  if triggerpos("alt_delta",200) and target_alt > alt_ind then

    XPLMSpeakString("Check your altitude.  You are too low.  Climb to " .. 
      target_alt .. " feet.")

  elseif triggerneg("alt_delta",-200) and target_alt < alt_ind then

    XPLMSpeakString( "Check your altitude.  You are too high.  Descend to " 
      .. target_alt .. " feet.")

  end
```

For the monitor, (as an example) I need to check the state of my scenario logic.  This is an integer, so it is a whole number.   For example:

```
monitor("scenario_state") and scenario_state=998
```

basically just asks if scenario_state has changed, and if so, did it change to a value of 998??  I don't care about what direction is changed, just that it DID change and to what value.

I searched the web for answers, but the code is all in C++ or java, and I can't understand it.  Please help... I'm a newbie... Sorry.

Comment: which engine is being used?

Comment: **triggerpos** is not a valid Lua name. Please read the Lua reference manual and maybe do a beginners tutorial. After that you should know what to do.

Comment: Well, a table key can be monitored using metatables, but why not simply cache the old value and compare it?

Comment: triggerpos is just a made up function name with two input parameters:  The variable to monitor, and the value when it should trigger. Yes, I would like to cache the old value and compare it to the new one.   I just cant wrap my brain around the correct code to do this.   How do deal with var_test is where I am stumped.  Remember, I am a newbie, so what may seem obvious to most is not to me.  What would the code look like in the code bock inside the triggerpos function?

Comment: The variable name is a string, then it needs to be converted to a variable , then I need to find the value for the variable at time x, then get the value for the variable again at time y.   Doing the comparison part is easy once I have the values cached.

Comment: `function triggerpos_func (varname, value_test)
 for i=1,2,1 do
  if i == 1 then
  value_test1 = _G[varname]
  else
  value_test2 = _G[varname]
  delta_value = value_test2 - value_test1
  end
 end`

Comment: I tried this code, but it is returning a nil for value_test2.  I think the _G key is what I need to use.. after reading the discussion  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007285/how-to-define-variable-that-named-by-function?rq=1

Comment: This is a classic example of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147573) - you have a goal (detect deviations in altitude) and a solution in mind (monitor changes in a variable), but you're investigating how to implement that solution, rather than whether there are alternative approaches that might be simpler or more robust. I don't mean to be critical - we all run into these sort of situations every day. I point it out simply because it's a useful problem solving anti-pattern to be aware of.